# data don't appear in datagrid every time

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, datagrid

I have a MDI application with 2 windows each containing a datagrid (implemented `DataGridView.CellValueNeeded`). I get the data from a MSSQL database using nhibernate.

First window called "employee", containing name, street, birth date, ... : `class Employee`

Second window called "work-time recording", containing hours, which project, name of employee, ... : `class WorkTimeRecording` (this class has a variable from type Employee)

When I open my application with just the "work-time recording" window, all data are shown correctly in the grid. When I open the application with both windows, the name of employee is missing in the work time recording datagrid.
Then I scroll in the employee datagrid to the appropriate person (and because of CellValueNeeded the data of this person is just loading in this moment). When I now switch back to work time recording datagrid, the name appears correctly.

But I want, that all data are shown directly, no matter which windows are open.

Any hints where I can start to search?

**NHibernate mapping**

```
<class name="WorkTimeRecording" table ="[WorkTime-Recording]" lazy="false">
..
<property name="IDEmployee" column="[ID-Employee]" />
```

Comment: can you able to clear your requirements .

Comment: My requirements are, that all data in the grid (also the name) will be displayed

Comment: form the question i was not clear what u require. and the requirement i understand is that the when u open the second window from the main window the name are not displaying in the grid.. is it??

Comment: if it is correct there is some problem with the foreign key relation

Comment: can u provide your code for my further reference to clarify

Comment: I added the nhibernate mapping. I think foreign key is generelly working, because when I open only the "work-time recording" window, the data appears. It seems that something block the data, when I open the "employee" window.

Comment: then use a thread and inside the thread call  the Employee window

Comment: Hmm...i don't think that this solves the problem. In my application I have this construct a lot of times, and it works always. I think its something with nhibernate...

Comment: ok,then can u please paste your code here let me check and replay

Comment: Yes, randomly throwing additional threads at the problem without a clear understanding of threads and how they are supposed to fix the issue will just increase your problems. However, there is nowhere near enough information provided to figure it out. You need to analyze/debug your code step by step to figure out which code is never called, and why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was, that my former colleague implemented the function with different levels of collecting data. The class WorkTimeRecording  has different depths (basic, medium, complete - the reason is to get performance and just loading the data to the repository, which were needed) to fill the instance. When I switched to complete, the variable employee in WorkTimeRecording was filled correctly, no matter which other Windows were open.

So it's not a nhibernate issue as I thought, but loading enough data at the right time... and to understand the code, other people have written ;)